# Concat messages.properties with maven

Tags: maven, properties, internationalization, translation

We have some default message files and we want to be able to customize them by maven profiles.

Therefore we configured two resource entries

```
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/profiles/${additionalWebcontent}/java</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
```

currently the files from `${basedir}/resources` are overwritten by files from `${basedir}/profiles/${additionalWebcontent}/java`.

Is it possible to append the content from the files from `${basedir}/profiles/${additionalWebcontent}/java` to the content of the files from `${basedir}/resources` ?

An example content would be

```
${basedir}/resources/messages/messages.properties
greeting=Hello World!
logout=Logout
login=Logout


${basedir}/profiles/${additionalWebcontent}/java/messages/messages.properties
greeting=Hello Folks!
```

Expected Result:

```
${project.build.directory}/classes/messages/messages.properties
greeting=Hello World!
logout=Logout
login=Logout
greeting=Hello Folks!
```